# Yet another question on Rudin's proof of the Weierstrass approximation theorem

Tags: real-analysis

This question seems not covered by other questions in this forum.

The proof of convergence uses the fact that $\int_{-1}^1 Q_n(t)\,dt=1$ to get $f(x)$ inside the integral when evaluating the estimate on $|P_n(x)-f(x)|$.  Uniform continuity is used to get $|f(x+t)-f(x)|$ smaller than $\frac \epsilon 2$ on the $t$-interval $[-\delta,\delta]$.  But the estimate is supposed to hold for all $x$ with $0\le x\le 1$.  At both $x=0$ and $x=1$, this is a problem because $f(x+t)$ is either not defined or 0 when $x+t>1$ or $x+t<0$.  In either case $|f(x+t)-f(x)|$ will be undefined or not controlled in size.

The only fix that I can think of is to define $f(x)$ to be $f(0)$ when $x<0$ and $f(1)$ when $x>1$.  This makes other parts of the proof a bit more confusing, but they seem to push through by saying the right things.  Details omitted.

I would appreciate learning that I am wrong in worrying about this point.

Comment: You need not necessarily extend $f$ so that the extension is constant on $(-\infty,0]$ and on $[1,+\infty)$, any extension to a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ (or even only $[-\eta,1+\eta]$ for some $\eta > 0$) works.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: I would agree.  But some continuous extension does seem to be necessary.  Is that right?

Comment: Indeed. But Rudin explicitly does that, he considers only functions $f \in C([0,1])$ with $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, and (after elaborating why that suffices), he writes "Furthermore, we define $f(x)$ to be zero for $x$ outside $[0,1]$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous on the whole line." Maybe that was missing in earlier editions.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: I completely missed that.  I went from the statement directly into the "guts."